# ExtJS: ViewPort with vertical scroll bar

Tags: javascript, extjs

I have 4-5 grid panels, one form panel and want to put it into one viewport.

Here the code:

```
var panel = new Ext.Viewport({
    layout: 'vbox',
    items:[SearchForm,1_grid_panel,2_grid_panel,3_grid_panel]
});
```

It woks very well, but im need horizontal scroll box because 3rd grid panel located under visible area. How I can add this scroll box?

**Update:** Example of one grid

```
var 1_grid_panel = new Ext.grid.GridPanel({
    store: some_store,
    flex:2,
    height: heightOfGrid,
    autoExpandColumn: 'id_md_dog',
    plugins: expander ,
    view: new Ext.grid.GroupingView({
        markDirty: false
    }),
    tbar: new Ext.PagingToolbar({
        pageSize: 100,
        store: some_store,
        displayInfo: true,
        displayMsg: 'text',
        emptyMsg: "No topics to display"
    }),
    columns: []
});
```

Comment: your grids available at once or you have links to change viewed grid? If second, how do you load data? which event if fired or another methods

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you tried `autoScroll: true` ?

Comment: then you should probably post more of your code, so people can help you troubleshoot

Comment: hm - which part of code you need? here about 1000 lines of code :)

Comment: I think you want to use either height or flex, but not both together for the same item. The box layout positions all items with defined heights, and then gives out the remaining viewport area to other items based on relative flex values

Comment: thx. Im tryed use only flex, then only height and scroll at viewport dont worked after that too ;( Another ideas?

Comment: im read what viewport doesnt support scrolling :( Mbe you know how i can located 4-5 grids with one form in vertcal view with scroll bar?

Comment: You can put a single container/panel with autoScroll as a child of the Viewport, and move all your grids to be child items of this container

Answer (score 1):

Ah, I really forgot. You need to describe next app structure: Viewport->Panel->items(your grids). Panel must have layout: fit
If I correctly understand your problem.